# Infinitely nested comments. How can I maintain a stack history?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a list adapter that allows the user to launch a new instance of the same Activity by pressing one of the items:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(ParseConstants.KEY_OBJECT_ID, commentId);
intent.putExtra(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, userId);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that I'm already in CommentActivity. If I write `(Activity) mContext.finish()` before launching the new Intent I will get to where I want to go, but then when the user presses back I return to very first Activity in the stack, which is MainActivity. I want to return the previous CommentActivity. How can I resolve this?

**Manifest Entry:**

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.CommentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.CommentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Comment: There will be an entry in your application manifest for CommentActivity.  Please include that manifest entry in your question  (or examine it to determine why you are seeing the behavior your describe.)

Comment: ... and remove `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`  I don't think it does what you want to do.

Comment: @DaleWilson I included the Manifest entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag you are telling Android to start a new Task  (collection of Activities) to contain the new Activity rather than pushing the new Activity onto the stack associated with the current Task.

When the Activity exits, the Task is empty so you return from the root of the Application.

What you want to do is push the new Activity onto the existing stack.  This is the default behavior, so remove the

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

line.

[Read more about Tasks and Activities here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: @DaveWilson Removing that line doesn't launch the new Activity... When I include ``((Activity) mContext).finish();`` before calling the new Intent I can get into the new Activity, but that destroys my back stack, but I want to preserve that.

Comment: Yeah, problem solved by removing both ``intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`` and ``android:launchMode="singleTask"`` from my manifest. Thanks!